# Extract key value pairs from various configuration files

Tags: parsing, nlp

I am attempting to build a program which restricts users from modifying certain configuration parameters across a variety of items. For example, I would like to allow a user to upload the nginx.conf file or a preconfiguration file for the linux OS, then be able to identify the key value pairs in these files (which may have different delimiters), extract these KV pairs and store them in a database somewhere.

As there are a wide variety of config file structures out there, I was thinking along the lines of using an NLP library which could look for these KV pairs (as opposed to a function in my program based on standard delimiters). Is there anything that you've used before or would recommend? A Go library would be a bonus as my program is currently written in Go.

Comment: This is not NLP, you just have different structured formats that you didn't identify properly. It looks to me like the goal is not well specified: even assuming you can parse key-values pairs, how would your program decide which pairs are restricted? which ones are stored? and how would this storage be reused? Start by doing the simplest scenario you can think of, then if this works you can think of improving.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Erwan. The restriction of the KV pairs are part of another function with the application. My questions simply relates to identifying KV pair structures within a document which could have a number of structures which are not within my control. E.g. key1=value1 or key1 value1 or key1:value1 or "key1":"value1". Each document would have the same type of structure, but there may be multiple documents types which each would have different structures.

Comment: Imho you could just take a sample of possible input formats, analyze the different patterns which exist in this sample and read these. Anyway an NLP solution would require training a model with a sample as well, but also probably annotating these. Additionally a ML solution means that there can be errors, would it be ok for your software to store wrong key/value pairs? If not, it's much better to accept only a limited number of formats correctly rather then accepting any format with a high risk of error.